# Fetch Data from Sqlite Database using Sqlite Plug-in (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to fetch data from Sqlite database using a sqlite plug-in in phonegap but I seem to be missing something. It doesn't report error when I checked the logcat but instead the database was opened successfully but my code won't fetch the data.

Below is my code so far...

```
function ViewData(id){

 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "mydb", 100000);

 db.transaction(function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userid=?', [id],
    function(transaction, result) {


      var row = result.rows.length;

      if(row>0){
      //fetch saved data
        alert(result.rows.item(0)['lname']);


      }

         },errorHandler);
      },errorHandler,nullHandler);

   return ;

 }
```

Note:
1. The error handler, success handler and null handler are well coded.

Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, i was calling the function before `onDeviceReady`